# Jackson hibernate module - eager on specific request

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jackson

Suppose I have a relation Customer 1 -> n Servers, declared as `FetchType.LAZY`. For the case when I show a list of customers, I don't want to bring the related entities, so response like

```
[{
  "name": "WooHoo",
  "servers": null
},
...
]
```

is totally fine, but when I want to show a specific customer, I'd like to make an eager call & serialize it to json, e.g

```
{
  "name": "WooHoo",
  "servers": [{
    "ip": "127.0.0.1",
    "username": "admin"
  },
  ...
  ]
}
```

Here is my *spring mvc* configuration for message converter.

```
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter(Hibernate5Module module){
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(module);

        messageConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
        return messageConverter;

    }

    @Bean
    public Hibernate5Module hibernate5Module() {
        return new Hibernate5Module();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(jacksonMessageConverter(hibernate5Module()));
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
```

How can I force eager call + related entities serialization (up to first level of relations) for a specific request?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using hql for loading a single customer.

From [Chapter 14. HQL: The Hibernate Query Language](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html):

> A "fetch" join allows associations or collections of values to be initialized along with their parent objects using a single select. This is particularly useful in the case of a collection. It effectively **overrides the outer join and lazy declarations** of the mapping file for associations and collections. See [Section 19.1, “Fetching strategies”](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching) for more information.